# extraer info de API

Tags: python, json, api

Actualmente tengo un csv de kaggle sobre movies al que he convertido en un DB,quiero enriquecerlo usando una API  gratuita,he pensado en filmaffinity y de ahí extraer las pelis del 2006 al 2016(que es con las que estoy trabajando en mi DB), ver si están en mi DB y extraer su rating.La verdad que no entiendo muy bien el tema de las APIS cómo puedo hacer esto.
¿Dónde puedo encontrar explicaciones y ejemplos sobre APIS?
PD:He encontrado un par de repos en github que dicen ser APIS no oficiales de filmaffinity.
Edito:he probado en un sitio de apis gratis quiero ocultar mi apikey,estoy probando con esta función, sin embargo ,me genera un error de sintaxis:

````
    url = f"https://imdb8.p.rapidapi.com{endpoint}"
    querystring = {"tconst":"tt0944947"}
    apiKey = os.getenv("RAPIKEY")
    if not apiKey:
        raise ValueError("Please setup the GITHUB_APIKEY env variable")
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb8.p.rapidapi.com"
        "Authorization": f"token {apiKey}"
    }
    
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(res.url)
    return res.json()```
````

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta se puede considerar basada en opiniones, y probablemente termine cerrada. ://

Comment: No hay una API como tal que te permita hacer lo que tu quieres, pero si es posible combinar [esta API](https://github.com/carlosramosa/api-filmaffinity#ejemplos-de-uso) con un solicitud directa a la página de filmaffinity. Mi idea sería la siguiente:

1. Dado un título (no podríamos buscar por fechas, así que comprobaríamos directamente lo que tengas en la DB) solicitar en la API el código que tiene en filmaffinity
2. Con ese código, hacer una petición HTTP a la página oficial y con web scrapping obtener la valoración.
Si el resultado te convence... se puede intentar

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obtener el código filmaffinity de una película dada su nombre

```
# Voy a poner un nombre de ejemplo, pero habría que recorrerlo con todos los de la DB
film = "Lo que el viento se llevó (1939)"
```

2. Solicitar el código de film con la API.

Estaremos para ello usando [esta aAPI](https://github.com/carlosramosa/api-filmaffinity#ejemplos-de-uso)

```
# Como tenemos que solicitarlo siguiendo el formato de la API, debemos crear un "link", donde los espacios
#se convierten en "+"
para_sol = film.replace(" ", "+")

# Ahora empezamos a trabajar con la API, lo único que nos interesa es el código, y sabemos que la respuesta
# viene en formato de JSON, por lo que importamos lo necesario
import json
import requests

# Se trata de hacer una solicitud web (más o menos). Por lo que necesitamos nuestro link
BASE_URL =  "https://api-filmaffinity.herokuapp.com/api/busqueda/" # (https://github.com/carlosramosa/api-filmaffinity#ejemplos-de-uso)

# Y le añadimos lo que queremos consultar
r = BASE_URL + para_sol # Tendremos ahora el link con la peli que buscamos

# Así que lanzamos la solicitud a la API
sol = requests.get(r)

# La respuesta que almacenamos es el código de solicitud HTTP, si queremos la respuesta en sí, debemos pedirle el "texto"
respuesta = sol.text
print(respuesta)
```

```
[OUT]: [{"titulo":"Lo que el viento se llevó (1939) - Filmaffinity","id":"https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film470268"},{"titulo":"Sólo los ángeles tienen alas (1939) - Filmaffinity","id":"https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film304823"}]
```

Como vemos tiene varias respuestas (supongo que por coincidencias en el texto o lo que sea). Yo me quedo con una y vía (habría que escribir algo de código para seleccionar la mejor respuesta).

```
# Tenemos que convertirlo a JSON
JSON = json.loads(respuesta)
url = JSON[1]["id"] + ".html"
print(url)
```

```
[OUT]: https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film304823.html
```

3. Obtener valoración con web scrapping

```
# Para ello importaré la librería bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Y ahora lo solicitamos y lo parseamos
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# Soup lo que contiene básicamente es el código html de todo el url
# Observando la página, averiguamos que podemos identificar la valoración
# mediante el div que lo contiene (por su id)
div = soup.select("div[id^=movie-rat-avg]") # Buscamos el div que tiene por id "movie-rat-avg"
print(div)
```

```
[OUT]: [<div content="7.7" id="movie-rat-avg" itemprop="ratingValue">
                        7,7                    </div>]
```

```
rating = div[0]["content"]
```

Y en rating tendríamos la valoración. Lo realmente difícil sería el punto 1 (pasar las pelis del DB al nombre de filmaffinity, si eso funciona correctamente, el resto va rodado). Si necesaitas más información que quieras añadir, puede verse en el punto 3 que es simplemente ver donde está en la página original y después añadirlo al código. Espero que valga para el propósito que tenías aunque no fuese del modo que tu querías.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta,el web scrapping es la segunda parte del ejercicio que estoy haciendo,probaré con lo que me has comentado!!